# Nginx ssl_preread cannot handle SOCKS 5 Proxy protocol

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, socks, pass-through

I'm trying to run SSL and Non-SSL (in my case SOCKS 5 proxy) protocols over the same port in Nginx 1.17. This works for SSH very well according to [Nginx document](https://www.nginx.com/blog/running-non-ssl-protocols-over-ssl-port-nginx-1-15-2/). But it's not working for Socks proxy and it times out. I believe the problem is with `ssl_preread on` because when I remove it and forward all traffic to socks upstream, it works without a problem. Does Nginx have problems in handling Socks 5 Proxy with ssl_preread on?

```
stream {
    upstream socks {
        server 127.0.0.1:1080; #SOCKS 5 proxy server
    }

    upstream https {
        server 127.0.0.1:8443;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_protocol $upstream {
        default socks;
        "TLSv1.2" https;
        "TLSv1.3" https;
        "TLSv1.1" https;
        "TLSv1.0" https;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass headers Upgrade and Connection to the proxied server, see https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

```
  ...
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
  }

  server {
     listen 443;
     proxy_pass $upstream;
     ssl_preread on;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  }
  ...
```

Comment: The problem is when I use `ssl_preread`, the connection doesn't close. But unfortunately, I cannot use proxy_http_version, proxy_set_header and proxy_set_header inside server block (in stream).